# convert jagged array of System::Byte to unsigned char**

Tags: c++, arrays, byte, clr

I would like to implement a C++\CLI function that convert a jagged array of System::Byte to unsigned char**. 
I made this:

```
unsigned char**     NUANCECLR::IsItYou::convertBBtoCC(array<array<System::Byte>^>^ b)
{
    unsigned char** x = NULL;
    for (size_t indx = 0; indx < b->Length; indx++)
    {       
            if (b[indx]->Length > 1)
            {
                pin_ptr<System::Byte> p = &b[indx][0];
                unsigned char* pby = p;
                char* pch = reinterpret_cast<char*>(pby);
                x[indx] = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(pch);
            }
            else
                x[indx] = nullptr;
    }
    return x;
}
```

I can't test it currently, maybe someone can help me, tell me if it is ok or not, because I need it relatively fast.Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not OK. This will bow up in your face a number of different ways:

```
unsigned char**     NUANCECLR::IsItYou::convertBBtoCC(array<array<System::Byte>^>^ b)
{
    unsigned char** x = NULL;
```

No storage allocated. `x[anything]` will be invalid.

```
    for (size_t indx = 0; indx < b->Length; indx++)
    {       
            if (b[indx]->Length > 1)
            {
                pin_ptr<System::Byte> p = &b[indx][0];
```

this pining pointer will go out of scope at the end of this if block and unpin. The system may once again move or delete at will

```
                unsigned char* pby = p;
```

This takes a pointer to an array of object wappers around a byte and assigns it to an array of `char`. I won't claim expertise here, but I don't believe this will work transparently without a lot of hidden voodoo.

```
                char* pch = reinterpret_cast<char*>(pby);
```

This will actually work, but becasue the previous likely doesn't, I don't expect `pch` to point at anything meaningful.

```
                x[indx] = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(pch);
```

As stated above, `x` doesn't point at any storage. This is doomed.

```
            }
            else
                x[indx] = nullptr;
```

also doomed

```
    }
    return x;
```

and still doomed.

```
}
```

Recommendation:

1. Allocate unmanaged storage with `new` for a `char *` array of size `b->Length` and assign to `x`
2. Allocate unmanaged storage with `new` for a `char` array of size `b[indx]->Length` and copy all of the elements of `b` into it, then assign to `x[indx]`.
3. return `x`
4. ensure all the arrays pointed to by `x` and then `x` are deleted when you're done with them. Or use `vector<vector<char>>` instead of `char**`.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I forgot about allocation, my brain is KO :)